# Do I need some amplifier for my VST instruments Ample Metal Eclipse and Ample Metal Rays to get the tone of Metal?

Tags: guitar, bass-guitar, tone, vst, metal

I want to tune these instruments to get the tone of metal especially metalcore tone.

Here is my guitar Ample Metal Eclipse :

[image]

and here is my bass :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need some amplifier for my VST instruments Ample Metal Eclipse and Ample Metal Rays

The products you have (https://www.amplesound.net/en/pro-pd.asp?id=18, https://www.amplesound.net/en/pro-pd.asp?id=16) both say they already have a "AMP Simulator" / "Built-in AMP system". Have you identified a problem with this? If not, then there is no reason to think that you need another amp simulator. (Using a real amplifier would be a very strange choice, as the whole point of these products is to do everything inside the computer.)

> What can you say about my remix, is this metal tune?

No, to me it doesn't sound like metal. As Laurence Payne says, to get a good guitar sound, you need to reproduce the necessary articulations and playing techniques.

Possibly, you need to spend more time learning about how the guitar works, and how these products work. Or maybe the products aren't suitable for what you are trying to do.

Technology is always improving, but it might be easier for you to learn to play a real guitar than to get a realistic sound out of these products.

Comment: I think they're advanced since I can see many settings there in those two products. Maybe I need to learn exactly about how to produce harmonics out of these. Did you mean that I should recompose that song notes or what?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "recompose the song notes"?

Comment: I meant rearrangement of the music sheet.

Comment: Aha - yes, to change the genre of a piece you can't just play the same notes with a different sound. You should learn how metal songs work - how the instruments are played, and how the sounds are processed - and try to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no set answer to that question.  You certainly COULD reamp your guitar tracks by sending them out to an over-cranked speaker with a mic in front of it.  Or you could experiment with the many available effects that aim to emulate this 'in the box'.

I think your greater issue will be in reproducing the gestures - the actual playing techniques - of metal in a sequenced track.

Comment: I am just a geek not a musician so I can't understand what you said.

Comment: OK.  Just concentrate on choosing good notes to play for now then.  Tweaking the tone can come later, when you've GOT some music to tweak!

Comment: What can you say about my remix, is this metal tune?
https://soundcloud.com/tber-mohamed-mahdi/paragonx9-chaoz-fantasy-metal-remix

Comment: No, I wouldn't call that 'metal' even though it features a distorted guitar sound.   If you want to label the genre I'd say 'computer game'.